# Redis Geospatial Commands on Unstable Branch

Tags: redis

I am attempting to use the new Redis geospatial features documented [here.](http://redis.io/commands/geoadd) I understand that these features are slated for inclusion in Redis 3.2 and so are not included in a stable distribution. So, I pulled down the unstable tarball from the official website.

I ran

```
make && make test && sudo make install
```

I then fired up `redis-cli` to see if I could use the `GEOADD` command and was met with

```
(error) ERR unknown command 'GEOADD'
```

However, if I run `help GEOADD`,

```
  GEOADD key longitude latitude member [longitude latitude member ...]
  summary: Add one or more geospatial items in the geospatial index represented using a sorted set
  since: 
  group: geo
```

So, the help information for the geo commands is here. I thought that perhaps something was wrong with this tarball, so I instead cloned from github and checked out the `unstable` branch, only to be met with the same result. Checking out older commits since the functionality was implemented, I got the exact same result.

Looking through the directories, the proper geo-related files are being compiled, the commands just don't seem to be accessible from the CLI. Has anyone ever successfully used redis geospatial functionality on the unstable branch or am I attempting to use this feature prematurely?

Comment: I just tested on the latest unstable and it works fine. I'm guessing that you may have an older Redis running that you're actually connecting to. What info does `INFO` yield?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same situation happen when I upgraded from 3.0 to 3.2.  The symptom was interesting in that HELP displayed 3.2 and would intellisense style fill in function calls.  However, INFO displayed 3.0 still.

The answer for me on ubuntu was to:

```
sudo service redis_6379 stop`

sudo service redis_6379 start`

redis-cli`
```

after that both HELP and INFO reported 3.2 and GEO functions worked as documented and expected.

Comment: `HELP` displays information about `redis-cli`, not the redis server
whereas `INFO` shows information about the server.